# jquery is not working in rails once different yield is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using adminlte-2 theme in my project for the first time it will load all js file correctly.Once I click on any link it will not load the js files

Answer (score 1):

It is happening due to `turbolinks` in rails4, in your `<body>` tag in `application.html.erb` layout add the following line for a quick fix

```
<body data-no-turbolink>
```

**or**

You can also remove `turbolinks` gem from your Gemfile and corresponding js file from application layout.

**or**

In your javascript tag you can add `page:load` along with the `ready` event

```
ready = function(){
  // your code here
}
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Hope this helped!